# How to use different labels for Basic Authentication credentials Swagger 3

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-3.0

My API is currently using Basic Authentication with `api_xxx` instead of `username` and `api_xxy` instead of `password`, do we have any specific schema for such a situation?

Everything works exactly the same, I would like to change only the labels on the UI for username and password.

The following functionality is described as following:

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    basicAuth:     # <-- arbitrary name for the security scheme
      type: http
      scheme: basic
security:
  - basicAuth: []  # <-- use the same name here
```

Comment: Do you mean [these labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfQOh.png)?

Comment: Yes, the labels displayed on the UI for username:password.